# Some columns in SharePoint Online do not have Column Formatting available

Tags: sharepoint-online, choice-field, json-formatting, column-formatting

Why do I not have an option to format columns? Other lists on the same site do.

[image]

Comment: Is this a site column or list column?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the **list settings** page -> **Advanced Settings**

At the bottom of the page, we could see **List experience**

Make sure - **New experience** radio button is selected. By default - **Default experience for this site** will be selected.

Note: With the **Default experience for this site** selection also should work.

Then open the list from modern experience... then we don't need to go to the list settings page to get **column formatting** option, we can get from the list view page only... we will get the JSON entry box like below:

[image: Format column in SharePoint Online]

Comment: Hi - if it has helped you, could you please [Upvote(^)] and mark as answered.